# how to display video file using the default player

Tags: java, opencv, video

is there any way to run a video file using the default media player installed in the system?

running the below posted code does not run the video player that should be used to play the .avi file, the below code just open the .avi file and provide some data about the each frame.

how to let video player plays the provided video file 
**Code**:

```
static final String aviPath = "C:\\private\\ArbeitsOrdner_19_Mar_2015\\AVIs\\parabole.avi";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    vCapture = new VideoCapture();
    matFrame = new Mat();
    clonedFrame = new Mat();

    try {
        vCapture.open(aviPath);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("no video found.");
        try {
            vCapture.open(WEB_CAM);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("No WEB_CAM attached.");
        }
    }

    if (vCapture.isOpened()) {
        while (vCapture.grab()) {

            vCapture.retrieve(matFrame);
            if (!matFrame.empty()) {
                System.out.println("grabbed frame");
                System.out.println("frame size: " + matFrame.size());
                clonedFrame = matFrame.clone();
                //showInFrame(clonedFrame);
            }
        } vCapture.release();
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Use Desktop to play files with their native applications instead of writing a player with JMF.

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\path\to\file.avi"));

This will play the file with whatever player is currently set as the default program i.e VLC or Windows Media Player